# how to calculate Jaccard index using segmented image with contour of original iamge in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I have segmented image and i got the contour of original image using this command imcontour(original_image,1) and then i have used this code to calculate the jaccard index in matlab.I am new in matlab please help me.Here is the code that i have used

```
 function [jaccardIdx,jaccardDist] = jaccard_coefficient(img_Orig,img_Seg)  
   img_Orig = logical(img_Orig);
   img_Seg = logical(img_Seg);
   if ~islogical(img_Orig)
        error('Image must be in logical format');
   end
   if ~islogical(img_Seg)
        error('Image must be in logical format');
   end
   inter_image = img_Orig & img_Seg;
   union_image = img_Orig | img_Seg;
   jaccardIdx = sum(inter_image(:))/sum(union_image(:));
   jaccardDist = 1 - jaccardIdx;
```

but and at the time of intersection of 2 images, error is comming that is Matrix dimensions must agree and i am not able to resolve it.Thanks in advance please help me.

Comment: The function seems to be ok. maybe the input arguments are invalid.
what are the dimensions of the input parameters img_Orig and img_Seg?

Comment: @droco what do you mean by dimension of image are you talking about size?

Comment: add the following lines to the beggining of your function:
size1 = size(img_Orig);
size2 = size(img_Seg);
what are the values of size1 and size2?

Comment: @droco size1 =121   167 and size2 = 120   161

Comment: @droco i donot understand why i am getting different size because before calling the function i am using img_ori = imresize(img_ori, 0.5); to resize the images

Comment: It seems that their dimensions were different before performing the resizing. for more information see my answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments I understand that the reason for the failure is the fact that you are using matrices with different dimensions: the ground truth image is bigger than the segmentation image([121 167] vs [120 161]).

In general, these images should have the same size in order to calculate the ir jaccard index. You'll need to check why did you get different sizes in the first place.

If you are 100% sure that it's not a bug, you can perform resizing of segmentation image according to the the size of the ground truth:

```
segImage = imresize(segImage,size(origImage));
```